# Changing the font size of all the sections or sub sections

Tags: fonts, sectioning, chapters

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\section{Hello World}
{\fontsize{20}{24}\selectfont
\lipsum[4]
}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

Here I can modify the font for a section , How write a command for all the sections or subsections to have the font size specified?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply remove the braces from around `\fontsize{20}{24}\selectfont`

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\section{Hello World}
\fontsize{20}{24}\selectfont
\lipsum[1-40]

\end{document}
```

But this gives aweful result. You can use `extsizes` package as one option (other options do exist if you are interested).

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{microtype}   %% beautifies spacings.
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[20pt]{extsizes}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\Blinddocument
\end{document}
```

[image]